# Is every function from $R^\omega$ to $R^\omega$ with uniform topology continuous?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, product-space

So I was studying topology and I came across the next theorem:

A function $f: X \to Y$ is continous iff for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that
if $d_x(x,y)<\delta$ then $d_y(f(x), f(y))<\epsilon$.

Since every distance in the uniform topology is at most 1, the theorem will always be true for any function from $R^\omega$ to $R^\omega$ with the uniform topology, am I wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by uniform topology?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy according to the Munkres is the topology induced by the distance:
$\bar{\rho}(x,y)= sup(min(|x_i-y_i|, 1) ), i \in \mathcal{N}$

Comment: **all** $\epsilon>0$ can be equivalently replaced by all $\epsilon \in (0,1)$ and ditto for $\delta$, and then the cutting off of the metric has no effect at all. So your idea is delusional.

Comment: Continuity is about getting arbitrarily close so especially for $\varepsilon$ very close to $0$. The cutting off of the metric at $1$ is just a technical thing to make the sup well-defined for all pairs of ponits and it doesn't affect those small distances at all. "Locally" everything is still the same distance as without the cutting off.

Answer (score 1):

Counter-example: $f(x_i)=(y_i)$  where $y_i=1$ if $x_i \geq 0$ and $y_i=0$ if $x_i < 0$. This function is not continuous because $(0,0,...,0,\frac {(-1)^{n}} n,\frac {(-1)^{n+1}} {n+1},... ) \to (0,0,...)$ but $d((0,0,...,0,\frac {(-1)^{n}} n,\frac {(-1)^{n+1}} {n+1},... ), f(0,0,...))=1$ for all $n$. [Here $(0,0,...,0,\frac {(-1)^{n}} n,\frac {(-1)^{n+1}} {n+1},... )$ starts with $n-1$ zeros].

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How does the function fail to fulfill the theorem?

Comment: For $\epsilon=1$ there is no $\delta$: Take $x=(0,0,...,0,\frac {(-1)^{n}} n,\frac {(-1)^{n+1}} {n+1},... )$ and $y=(0,0,0,...)$. @JocsanArielHernandezBarahon